# Disabled text box accessible using tab key

Tags: html, css, textbox, disabled-control

i have two text boxes on a form.One is the Enabled text box which is editable 
and another one is the Disabled text box which is not editable.I have disabled
it using a css style.
The issue that i'm facing is that i'm able to access disabled textbox
using the tab key of the keyboard like if i click on the enabled text
box and press tab it moves to the disabled text box and i'm able to enter
text in it.

Here is the sample html code

```
    <input type="textbox" placeholder="Enabled" />
<div class="notEdit-overlay"></div>
<div>
    <input type="textbox" placeholder="Disabled" />
</div>
```

Here is the css style

```
    .notEdit-overlay
{
    width: 1080px;
    height: 99%;
    left: 0px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXmvy/)

Comment: Why not actually disable it? `disabled="disabled" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the disabled attribute on your input.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="disabled" />
```

Also; there is no input type textbox, if you want the big one, use `<textarea>value</textarea>`

Answer (score 2):

Assign the disabled box a `tabindex` of -1

i.e. `<input type="textbox" placeholder="Disabled" tabindex="-1" />`